# Finding what original Maven dependency gets overriden

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

After adding the following dependency to pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.timgroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-statsd-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Eclipse complains:

```
Overriding managed version 3.1.0 for java-statsd-client
```

How would I find out where (in which existing dependency) is that overriden version resides?

---

Tried the suggestion by @Evan LaHurd - here's what I'm getting in Eclipse:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Typically in a parent pom specifying a `dependencyManagement` section.

Comment: Less typically, but, I guess, possibly, in a dependency of type `pom`, scope `import`, or simply in the `dependencyManagement` section of the very same pom.

Comment: @Tunaki - how do I see the parent pom within Eclipse or on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about how to see the parent pom.xml within Eclipse:

Open the POM file and navigate to the overview tab in the editor. There is a small icon with the tooltip "Open Parent POM" in the Parent section (it looks like a little sheet with an M on it and a yellow arrow).

From here you can look at the dependency management section like Tunaki said either in the Dependencies tab or directly in the pom.xml file.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  Unfortunately I'm getting an unresolved artifact message in Eclipse and no parent pom - see my updated answer.

Comment: What is the parent entry in your pom.xml file? Should be enclosed by `<parent></parent>`.

Comment: <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0.M4</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

Comment: Do you know where the parent pom.xml file is located? If so, just open it up with any file editor. Because you didn't specify a relative path to the parent pom.xml, you may be getting that error pop-up if the parent project isn't in the same directory structure as the child, or if the parent project isn't installed in your local Maven repository.